# ServiceStack Log Scrubbing

Tags: logging, servicestack

I am logging all API calls in ServiceStack via the build in logging mechanism. I am wondering if there is some way to intercept the log call and scrub the data before saving it to get rid of stuff like passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just implement your own adapter `ILogFactory` and `ILog` classes that acts like a proxy to the currently configured logger, e.g:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ScrubberLogFactory(LogManager.LogFactory);
```

ScrubberLogFactory would just be a wrapper and delegate calls to the real LogFactory, e.g:

```
class ScrubberLogFactory : ILogFactory
{
  ILogFactory logFactory;

  public ScrubberLogFactory(ILogFactory logFactory)
  {
    this.logFactory = logFactory;
  }

  public ILog GetLogger(Type type)
  {
    return new ScrubLogger(logfactory.GetLogger(type));
  }

  public ILog GetLogger(string typeName)
  {
    return new ScrubLogger(logfactory.GetLogger(typeName));
  }
}
```

ScrubLogger is another adapter class that intercepts all the logging calls which you can then do what you need (i.e. scrub the logging info) before delegating it to the underlying logger.